# Add first and last date of a sequence

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am working on a database which have a huge collection of rows. I want to update it so repeated records will be deleted. Now, I have a date `column` in table and I want to convert it into `startDate` and `endDate`. Please check:

```
    id    |      date      |  price  |  minutes  | prefixId  |  sellerId  |  routeTypeId  
   
   1234       2020-01-01      0.123        0          1            1              1
   1235       2020-01-04      0.123        0          1            1              1
   1236       2020-01-05      0.123      123          1            1              1
   1237       2020-01-06      0.123       31          1            1              1
   1238       2020-01-07      0.123       23          1            1              1
   1239       2020-01-08      0.130       41          1            2              1
   1240       2020-01-09      0.130        0          1            1              1
```

**What I am looking for is:**

```
    id    |   startDate   |    endDate   |  price  |  minutes  | prefixId  |  sellerId  |  routeTypeId  
   
   1234       2020-01-01     2020-01-01     0.123        0          1            1              1
   1235       2020-01-04     2020-01-07     0.123        0          1            1              1
   1239       2020-01-08     2020-01-08     0.130       41          1            2              1
   1240       2020-01-09     2020-01-09     0.130        0          1            2              2
```

Dates will be considered in a series if `price`, `prefixId`, `sellerId`, `routeTypeId` will remain same with previous row and `date` column generates a series (without any gap between dates. So, `2020-01-01`, `2020-01-2`, `2020-01-10` are two different series for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  You can use `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select price, prefixId, sellerId, routeTypeId,
       min(minutes),
       min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_date = date - interval '1 day' then 0 else 1 end) over (order by date) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(date) over (partition by price, prefixId, sellerId, routeTypeId order by date) as prev_date
            from t
           ) t
      ) t
group by grp, price, prefixId, sellerId, routeTypeId
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a "Gaps & Islands" problem. You can do it using:

```
select
  min(id) as id,
  min(date) as start_date,
  max(date) as end_date,
  min(price) as price,
  ...
from (
  select *,
    sum(inc) over(order by id) as grp
  from (
    select *,
      case when price = lag(price) over(order by id)
            and date = lag(date) over(
                 partition by price, prefixId, sellerId, routeTypeId 
                 order by id)
                 + interval '1 day'
           then 0 else 1 end as inc
    from t
  ) x
) y
group by grp
```